# SQL.. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite with python.

```
column1 |  column2    |
a       |      1      |
a       |      2      |
a       |      3      |
b       |      1      |
b       |      2      |
b       |      3      |
c       |      1      |
c       |      2      |
d       |      1      |
```

Is it possible to do something like this

I need to take column1's element name which has column2's 1,2,3 all.
so It should be [a, b]

With python, I usually use to select some.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT DISTINCT column1 from tablename where column2 = ? and column1 = ?''',("0", "a",))

print(cur.fetchall())
```

As you know, It is not related much with the problem.

Comment: That is relational division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
select column1
from t
where column2 in (1, 2, 3)
group by column1
having count(distinct col2) = 3;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
select column1
from t
where column2 in (1, 2, 3)
group by column1
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: `where column1 in (1, 2, 3)` should be `where column2 in (1, 2, 3)`, and you don't need to assume no duplicates - Sqlite supports `count(distinct...`

Comment: This assumes there are no duplicates in `column2`. I would replace the last line by: `having count(distinct column2) = 3`.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I would only do that if the OP suspects there are duplicates in the column.  Otherwise, the `distinct` adds unnecessary overhead.